# dbmail email from cmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, dbmail

Is it possible to send email attachment using dbmail from cmd? I'm using a batch file to send email attachment using dbmail but getting an error. Here is my code:

```
sqlcmd -q "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'ProfileName',
  @recipients='example@test.com',
  @subject='Test Attachment ',
  @body='Using dbmail to send attachment',
  @file_attachments='C:\document\example.txt'"
```

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'exec msdb.dbo.sp_send dbmail @profile_name='auditProfile'

Comment: @LitonUddin have you figured this out yet?